# Passing state and setstate together in React

Tags: reactjs

I want to pass a state and it's setState function together as a single property. Is that possible? Right now I have to do like: state={state} setState={setState} and it's kind of messy

Answer (score 4):

You could continue to use the array returned by `useState`:

```
const stateContainer = useState('foo');

// ...
return <SomeComponent {...{stateContainer}} />
```

And then in `SomeComponent`, extract the state and setter from the container.

```
const [state, setState] = stateContainer;
```

If you have to use the state and setter in the parent component too, you might want to continue destructuring the `useState` call, in which case shorthand property names are another option:

```
return <SomeComponent {...{state, setState}} />
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to create an object:

```
state={{
    state,
    setState,
}}
```